# Почтовый сервер (exim4). Как присвоить домену определенный ip?

Tags: linux, vpn, exim

Есть сервер на нем подключено несколько интерфейсов с адресами 192.168.x.x(каждый имеет внешний белый ip)
Есть панель управления, в нее добавлены несколько доменов.
Как настроить отправку почты с доменов:

```
domain1 – ip1 //eth0  
domain2 – ip2 //eth1
```

ip адреса имеют вид `192.168.x.x` и белый внешний ip адрес. Отправка почты идет, если пустить весь исходящий трафик через определенный интерфейс (ip route replace default via...), но если указать(в панели управления) домену какой-то адрес, я постоянно вижу: "Network is unrecheable..."

В чем может быть ошибка? Если указывать в панели управления или в domainips (`etc/exim4/domainips`), то опять же ошибка Network is unrecheable...

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, вывод команды `ip a; ip r`. если хотите сохранитеь анономность, можете у внешних адресов заменить старший октет на буквы (разные значения октетов — разные буквы). расшифруйте, что именно подразумеваете под `ip1` и `ip2`, и в какие ip-адреса резолвятся имена *mx-записей* для `domain1` и `domain2`. также не помешает и вывод команды `grep -r domainips /etc/exim*`.

Answer (score 1):

правильное написание правил решило проблему

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее рассказать о найденном решении, привести пример настроек? Это поможет будущим читателям вашего вопроса, у которых будет та же проблема.